# MySql datatype that's integer to store integers in a comma-separated way

Tags: mysql

What datatype can I use to store a value like `1,2,3,4,5`. I'd like them to remain as integers and not strings. I know I can use `varchar() or enum() or set()`, but those are strings. I'm using MySQL version `5.5.25`. The values being stored isn't fixed either. It could be `1` or `1,2,3`

Answer (score 2):

The proper data type is a table.  You can should store one value per row.

Typically, this would be an association table because the group of value would be assigned to some entity.  Something like:

```
create table EntityNumbers (
    EntityNumberId int auto_increment primary key,
    EntityId int references Entities(EntityId),
    Number int
);
```

Then, if you want to return the list, use `group_concat()`:

```
select EntityId, group_concat(Number)
from EntityNumbers
group by EntityId;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySql has no such datatype. The only datatype you can use to store multiple values in a single field is the [Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set.html) datatype, which only stores strings.

In a relational database, the usual solution for this problem is an additional table, with a foreign key to the original table, which may have multiple rows for each row in the original table.

So instead of

```
id | name | values
1  | foo  | 7,8,9
```

you would have

```
id | name 
1  | foo
```

and

```
id | foreign_key | value
1  |  1          | 7
2  |  1          | 8
3  |  1          | 9
```

and select them using

```
SELECT value from original_table join additional_table ON (id == foreign_key)
  WHERE original_table.id == 1
```

which results in 3 result rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
tinyint()  stores 1 byte 
smallint() stores 2 bytes
mediumint() stores 3 bytes
int() stores 4 bytes
```

Comment: ... and `bigint` is 8 bytes but these facts are unrelated to the question.